# Creating a table with scrambled and unordered data

Tags: bash, awk, grep, paste

I'm trying to create a nice little table of values and I'm doing it using bash, but not all the values are in order. Not only that the values also happen to be in their own file. My first few thoughts are to use cat and grep to grab the values, but from there I'm not sure what is appropriate. I feel like awk would do wonders in this situation, but I do not know awk very well.

file1 might look like this

```
V 0.001
A 98.6
N Measurement1
T 14:15:01
S 20.2
F 212.86
G 28.19
```

---

file2 might look like this

```
V 0.008
A 103.4
N Measurement2
T 16:20:31
S 21.2
F 215.86
G 28.19
```

---

The final file would look like this

```
N Measurement1 Measurement2
T 14:15:01     16:20:31
V 0.001        0.008
G 28.19        28.19
A 98.6         103.4
S 20.2         21.2
F 212.86       215.86
```

Comment: Try using `join`.

Comment: That's kind of nifty, but it doesn't really help me with getting values in order. Something else I noticed, join only works with 2 files, what if I want to add another file to a column?

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: @iSwimInTheC, are the 1st column values the same through all the files?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self commented, code is provided for understanding awk

```
awk '
     # cretate new reference (per file)
     FNR==1{Ref++}

     # each line
     { # add label to memory
     N[$1]
     # add value in 2 dimension array
     V[Ref ":" $1] = $2
     # remember maximum length of this serie
     if( length( $2 ) > M[Ref] ) M[Ref] = length(  $2 )
     }

     # after last file
     END{
        # print header (name of the serie)
        printf( "N ")
        for( i=1;i<=Ref;i++) printf( "%" M[i] "s ", V[ i ":N"  ] )
        printf( "\n")
        # print each data for this label (format suite the size to be aligned)
        # don t print a second time the name of the serie
        for ( n in N ){ 
           if( n != "N" ){ 
              printf( "%s ", n)
              for( i=1;i<=Ref;i++)  printf( "%" M[i] "s ", V[ i ":" n ] )
              printf( "\n")
              }
           }
        }
      ' file*
```